# Derived Column with multiple expressions VS multiple Derived Columns with one expression in each

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, derived-column

I use `SSIS` with `SQL Server 2016`. I need to know which below approach is better.

In one of my DataFlow task, I need to add more than 100 `Derived columns`. Should I add just one `Derived Column component` with 100 new `expressions` or should I add several `Derived Column component` in rows?

This is the first option:

[image]

And this is second option:

[image]

[image]

Which one is better?

Comment: @ArdalamShahgholi have u tried both methods? is there a difference between execution times?

Comment: if you tried both methods, plz provide execution times

Comment: I am in begin of my project, I don't have the real data yet. I have asked this question because I don't want have the problem in future.

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi if derived columns are independents you don't need to create multiples. i don't think you will find something else. i tried 2 methods they had Almost the same performance (one component is better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create multiple `derived column component` if derived columns  are independents, else you should create multiple components.

Also every added component inside the dataflow task has it's own properties that need validation. so i think it is better to minimize the number of components if it is doing the same thing.

---

Recently, I published a detailed article on this topic:

- [SQL Shack - SSIS Derived Columns with Multiple Expressions vs Multiple Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-derived-columns-with-multiple-expressions-vs-multiple-transformations/)

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi i made a deep search on that. Without finding anything new. The only thing that you can do is to try both of method and compare the elapsed time. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

You can add different expressions for multiple columns in one derived column transformation task. There is no need of adding multiple derived column.

Comment: As you can see in question, I am looking for the best way and why on way is better than other ones.